# QBXML get invoices of inactive customers

Tags: qbxml

How to retrieve invoices associated with *Inactive* customers.

```
 <InvoiceQueryRq  requestID='1495465099 0.44979100' iterator='Start'>
   <MaxReturned>50</MaxReturned>
   <TxnDateRangeFilter>
     <FromTxnDate>2017-01-01</FromTxnDate>
     <ToTxnDate>2017-05-22</ToTxnDate>
   </TxnDateRangeFilter>
   <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
 </InvoiceQueryRq>
```

This query does retrieve invoices, but only those associated with Active Customers. It does not return any invoices associated with Inactive Customers (and there really are some).

If I were retrieving a Customer, then I would use

```
ActiveStatus>All</ActiveStatus>
```

but the Onscreen Reference doesn't mention that with InvoiceQuery.

Comment: Have you tried searching by customer name to see if it can be found that way?

Comment: I'm using InvoiceQuery.  Do you mean with EntityFilter?  I tried <EntityFilter><FullName>DOE, John (REVOKED)</FullName></EntityFilter> after RefNumber, but got 0x80040400 which, I think is a syntax error.

Comment: I also tried EntityFilter with the (Inactive) Customer's ListID and the query was accepted, but no results returned. But the real requirement is to retrieve invoices within a date range for both active & inactive customers so customer identity won't usually be available.